# Moving the entire repository to new place with all earlier information like branch, committing etc

Tags: github, mercurial, repository, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I have some project on some repository. This repository is using Mercurial version of TortoiseHG. Now I want take this repo and put to the other repository using the same tool TortoiseHG but other repository for example Bitbucket or GitHub. How to move every commit and all branch and every information send before to new repository? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseHg is only a Mercurial client, not a Git client. So your Mercurial repository will stay as a Mercurial repository after you move it. GitHub does not support Mercurial, but Bitbucket does.

So you should go create a new Mercurial repository on Bitbucket. They will show you a guide when you create a new empty repository. You basically have to go do the `.hg/hgrc` file of the repository and change the `default` path so it looks like this:

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/your-username/your-repo
```

Then push like normal with `hg push` or with TortoiseHg. Mercurial will now send all the commits (including all branches) to the repository on Bitbucket.